# How to read 5V sensor signals on a 3.3V logic microcontroller?

Tags: microcontroller, power-supply, teensy

I have a Teensy 4.0 which cannot handle more than 3.3V on its IO pins. I have an ultrasonic sensor for which the minimum power supply is 3.3V. If I power the sensor with the Teensy's 3.3V source, it sends 3.3V signals to the Teensy's GPIO.

This is good, but sometimes the sensor does not turn on at a strict 3.3V due to manufacturing discrepancies or a shaky 3.28 or 3.29V power from the Teensy.

I can power the sensor with 5V from the Teensy but the sensor sends near 5V signals back to the Teensy's pins. I could power the sensor with a separate power supply that is a stable 3.3V source but that would be difficult to obtain.

There must be an easy solution to this.

Teensys work on 3.3V logic but should be able to work with 5V peripherals, I think.

They can also supply 5V but it doesn't make sense to supply 5V to devices that send 5V signals back to its GPIO pins. Maybe I am misunderstanding something.

Using a logic-level converter seems like overkill for just reading a sensor. I think those are more for I2C with different logic level SBCs and MCUs. I feel a voltage divider may mess up the signals of the sensor but I may be wrong.

Comment: You know what a voltage divider is, right?

Comment: is that the only way? but youre right im an idiot

Comment: No, but it's by far the simplest way.

Comment: For more solutions look nere: https://next-hack.com/index.php/2017/09/15/how-to-interface-a-5v-output-to-a-3-3v-input/

Comment: @Mike Very nice link. Some of the proposals are really over engineered.... ;-)

Answer (score 2):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fCkogD.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This is another way for high speed.